# How does Android's MediaPlayer work by checking the native code?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-mediaplayer

Checking the source code for `MediaPlayer` ([link](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java)), the `start()` method looks like this:

```
public  void start() throws IllegalStateException {
        stayAwake(true);
        _start();
}
```

And `_start()` method looks like this:

```
private native void _start() throws IllegalStateException;
```

Checking the native `_start()` method ([link](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/av/media/libmedia/mediaplayer.cpp#start)) (called `start()` but should it not be called `_start()` because of the native call was named `_start()`?):

```
status_t MediaPlayer::start()
{
    ALOGV("start");
    Mutex::Autolock _l(mLock);
    if (mCurrentState & MEDIA_PLAYER_STARTED)
        return NO_ERROR;
    if ( (mPlayer != 0) && ( mCurrentState & ( MEDIA_PLAYER_PREPARED |
                    MEDIA_PLAYER_PLAYBACK_COMPLETE | MEDIA_PLAYER_PAUSED ) ) ) {
        mPlayer->setLooping(mLoop);
        mPlayer->setVolume(mLeftVolume, mRightVolume);
        mPlayer->setAuxEffectSendLevel(mSendLevel);
        mCurrentState = MEDIA_PLAYER_STARTED;
        status_t ret = mPlayer->start();
        if (ret != NO_ERROR) {
            mCurrentState = MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_ERROR;
        } else {
            if (mCurrentState == MEDIA_PLAYER_PLAYBACK_COMPLETE) {
                ALOGV("playback completed immediately following start()");
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
    ALOGE("start called in state %d", mCurrentState);
    return INVALID_OPERATION;
}
```

Where is the data read? I wanted to check how Android work with RTSP but I could not find out where it loads the data. I wanted to know if it uses some library like FFMpeg or some other implementation.

EDIT:

Why was this code necessary to use JNI for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the following paths reference src/frameworks/base/.

In media/jni/android_media_MediaPlayer.cpp you will find the JNI code that forwards the Java method call to the underlying native framework. You can see the name mapping in the `gMethods[]` array and the `AndroidRuntime::registerNativeMethods` call near the bottom of the file. You can read more about registering native methods with JNI [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp5833), but that's not really the interesting part.

At this stage we are in the native counterpart of the Java `MediaPlayer`. For the most part, it doesn't do anything interesting, either. It binds to the `MediaPlayerService` through `IBinder` transactions. The `MediaPlayerService` creates the *actual* native player based on the type of media, and maintains a client (`MediaPlayerService::Client`) to facilitate communication with the native `MediaPlayer`, which in turn bubbles things back up to Java. You can see all this happen in the following files (if you're interested):

> media/libmedia/mediaplayer.cpp,
>   media/libmedia/IMediaPlayer.cpp,
>   media/libmedia/IMediaPlayerClient.cpp,
>   media/libmedia/IMediaPlayerService.cpp,
>   media/libmediaplayerservice/MediaPlayerService.cpp

Header files for libmedia are in include/media/libmedia/.

Now to the really interesting part, which are the component players. In MediaServicePlayer.cpp there are a couple of `getPlayerType` methods that decide what player to instantiate. There's Stagefright framework (AwesomePlayer and NuPlayer) and Sonivox player for MIDI. For RTSP, NuPlayer is what you'll get. You can find a glue layer in media/libmediaplayerservice/nuplayer/ and all the real source code in media/libstagefright/ and media/libstagefright/rtsp/.

Comment: I chose this as the answer because it was the most detailed and thoroughly written.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a step along the way. The `private native void _start()` in the Java code refers to [this entry](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/base/tree/media/jni/android_media_MediaPlayer.cpp?h=jb_mr1#n940) in the MediaPlayer JNI layer (which refers to [this function](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/base/tree/media/jni/android_media_MediaPlayer.cpp?h=jb_mr1#n415)).

As for the RTSP implementation, you'll probably find it among [the Stagefright sources](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/av/tree/media/libstagefright?h=jb_mr1).

Answer (score 0):

_start method is defined in jni in this mediaplayer file [link](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/base/media/jni/android_media_MediaPlayer.cpp)

from here that libmedia start method is getting called.